# Magento 2 Redirect to 3rd party payment gateway with post data

Tags: payment-methods, payment-gateway, magento-2.1

In Magento 1 we define the `getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl` in the model which extends `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract` and redirect to a particular controller after checkout submit. Then from the controller we call `$this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getLayout()->createBlock('someblock')->toHtml())` and inside the block we create a form with post data and redirect to a 3rd party payment gateway.

In Magento 2 i heard that `getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl` is not available and i'm unable to understand how it is handled. Can someone please guide me to achieve the above scenario in Magento 2.1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Magento 2 you have to create custom JavaScript component responsible for redirect to a Payment Provider. So how it works in Magento 2.

Custom redirect.html template with "Place Order" button should be created
This template is controlled by a redirect.js JavaScript component with `afterPlaceOrder` function inside which you can send HTTP GET request to your custom controller which will return parameters required for sending HTTP POST request to a payment gateway.

```
afterPlaceOrder: function () {
    var self = this;
    $.get(config.getDataUrl())
        .done(function (response) {
            customerData.invalidate(['cart']);
            formBuilder(response).submit();
        }).fail(function (response) {
            errorProcessor.process(response, self.messageContainer);
        }).always(function () {
            fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
        });
}
```

The `config.getDataUrl()` is custom controller URL. Here you do implement 2 different ways of POST parameters preparation. URL can be prepared from backend side and provided to a frontend by implementing the `\Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface::getConfig()` method.

Return key => value array of parameters as a response. The `formBuilder(response).submit()` will foreach parameters and prepare form which will be submitted to a payment provider as post.

```
var formTmpl =
    '<form action="<%= data.action %>" method="POST" hidden enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">' +
    '<% _.each(data.fields, function(val, key){ %>' +
    '<input value="<%= val %>" name="<%= key %>" type="hidden">' +
    '<% }); %>' +
    '</form>';

return function (response) {
    var inputs = {};
    for (var index in response.fields) {
        inputs[response.fields[index]] = response.values[index]
    }
    var hiddenFormTmpl = mageTemplate(formTmpl);
    var tmpl = hiddenFormTmpl({
        data: {
            action: response.action,
            fields: inputs
        }
    });
    return $(tmpl).appendTo($('[data-container="body"]'));
};
```

Render form wrapped in a `<html><body><form/></body></html>` on backend side using Block and `*.phtml` file with inline JavaScript inside the response. Once retrieved, JavaScript will trigger redirect. It is less recommended way but might be less time consuming.

Comment: Can you please answer following question:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219072/magento-2-post-order-details-to-third-party-payment-method