# Magento 2 - Post order details to third party payment method

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, uicomponent

Below is my payment-method.js

```
    define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
    ],
    function ($, Component, quote) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'NameSpace_CustomPayment/payment/testpayment'
            },

            placeOrder: function () {
                console.log(quote.billingAddress());
                $.mage.redirect('https://www.thirdparty.com');

            },

            getMailingAddress: function() {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.mailingAddress;
            }   
        });
    }
);
```

How can I post data of my quote object to third party.

Below is the sample Image to elaborate my query:
[image: Payment Description]

Answer (score 0):

#### Transfer data from the payment method form at checkout to the backend (order)

You can store additional data in the `additional_data` section of the payment, like this (in my case, I add this data in the method `getData` of my own payment method):

```
    /**
     * @return {Object}
     */
    getData: function () {
        let self = this;

        return {
            method: this.item.method,
            'additional_data': {
                'sender': self.sender(),
                'transaction_id': self.transaction_id(),
                'amount': self.amount(),
                'fee': self.fee(),
                'timestamp': self.timestamp(),
            }
        };
    },
```

then on the backend you can get this data this way:

```
/** @var \Magento\Payment\Model\MethodInterface $method */
$method->getInfoInstance()->getAdditionalInformation('your_data_key_here');
```

The method instance could be accessible from the quote or the order object:

```
/** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
$additionalInfoFromPayment = $order->getPayment()->getData('additional_information');
```

which returns your data from the checkout. Here mine example with data which I transferred from the checkout to the backend:

[image: Data example]

#### Transfer data from the backend to the js-payment method component

If you wish to transfer data from the backend to the payment method on the checkout the preferred way to do this is a use of the checkout config. Magento provides a simple way to do this:

1. Create your own checkout config provider class:

   ```
   <?php
   /**
    * Copyright © MageWorx. All rights reserved.
    * See LICENSE.txt for license details.
    */

   namespace MageWorx\WavesPayment\Model;

   use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;

   class WavesCheckoutConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
   {
       /**
        * @var \MageWorx\WavesPayment\Helper\Data
        */
       private $helper;

       /**
        * @var \MageWorx\WavesPayment\Helper\Rate
        */
       private $helperRate;

       /**
        * WavesCheckoutConfigProvider constructor.
        *
        * @param \MageWorx\WavesPayment\Helper\Data $helper
        * @param \MageWorx\WavesPayment\Helper\Rate $helperRate
        */
       public function __construct(
           \MageWorx\WavesPayment\Helper\Data $helper,
           \MageWorx\WavesPayment\Helper\Rate $helperRate
       ) {
           $this->helper = $helper;
           $this->helperRate = $helperRate;
       }

       /**
        * Retrieve assoc array of checkout configuration
        *
        * @return array
        * @throws \Exception
        */
       public function getConfig()
       {
           $output = [];

           if ($this->helper->isEnabled()) {
               // If method is not available - we do not display it on the checkout.
               // @see MageWorx/WavesPayment/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/waves-payments.js
               try {
                   $output['mageworx']['waves']['conversion_rate']   = $this->helperRate->getCurrentConversionRate();
                   $output['mageworx']['waves']['recipient_address'] = $this->helper->getRecipientAddress();
                   $output['mageworx']['waves']['available'] = true;
               } catch (\Exception $e) {
                   $output['mageworx']['waves']['available'] = false;
               }
           } else {
               $output['mageworx']['waves']['available'] = false;
           }

           return $output;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add this class to the `configProviders` of the `Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider` using the `frontend/di.xml`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <!--
   /**
    * Copyright © MageWorx. All rights reserved.
    * See LICENSE.txt for license details.
    */
    -->
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
       <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
           <arguments>
               <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="mageworx_waves_payment_config_provider" xsi:type="object">MageWorx\WavesPayment\Model\WavesCheckoutConfigProvider</item>
               </argument>
           </arguments>
       </type>
   </config>
   ```
3. Now you can access your info in the `js` component of your method using `window.checkoutConfig.mageworx.waves.available` (same path as in the config array)

Comment: Can you mention how can I use self instance here?

Comment: @DEEPJOSHI I updated my answer, if you have any questions, you can ask for clarification.

Comment: Thank you for the details
Can you elaborate more about how can I get data in Helper(Backend)
what are the classes I need to include in helper? Or what will be the structure of Helper?

Comment: @DEEPJOSHI Inject the `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface`, get your order by id using the `$orderRepository->get($id)` method, then you can access your data from the checkout like in my example: `$yourData = $order->getPayment()->getData('additional_information');`

Comment: I need to fetch data before order is placed, so here I guess there will be no order generated. Also can I implement same using Observer `DataAssignObserver`

Comment: @DEEPJOSHI So, in which place you want to obtain that data? I'm asking because it can be accessible right from the request in the `\Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest::processApiRequest()` where Magento set it to the payment method in the arguments, so anyway you can get your data from the payment (both quote and order). But they can be accessible only after the `placeOrder()` method called (in the js-component of your payment method).

Comment: I want to create my custom payment method.
My requirement is I want to post data to third party site and redirect user to that particular side. For example I am getting quote details in my js component, now how can I post that data to third party and redirect user?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74966/discussion-between-deep-joshi-and-siarhey-uchukhlebau).

Comment: @DEEPJOSHI Sorry for misunderstunding. I will update my answer according to your requiremets later.